# Is there a critical edition of Bhāgavata Purāṇa?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, critical-edition

There's a critical edition of [Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa](http://bombay.indology.info/ramayana/welcome.html) and there's one for [Mahābhārata](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html). Does Bhāgavata Purāṇa also have a critical edition?

If it does, maybe it will help answering questions like *[Questions regarding the number of verses in the Bhagavtam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19668)*

Also, which recension of Bhāgavata was used for the [ISKCON translation](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/)?

Comment: You can ask at publishing house BBT, Bhaktivedanta Book Trust, how they prepared Iskcon publication of Bhagavatam. I'm not sure does critical edition of Bhagavatam exist, but my personal opinion is that there is no need for such edition if you are not researcher or scientist or so. To the average reader BBT edition is quite enough. Bhagavatam is said to be one of the best preserved Puranas, perhaps the best preserved of all of them, and because of that the differences between manuscripts of the Bhagavatam are not great compared to other Puranas which manuscripts differ much greater.

Comment: Iskcon or say Gaudiya acaryas have followed Sridhara Swami's reading of the verses. Madhva edition had chapters 12,13,14 of 10th canto missing. Sridhara Swami has commented on these as well. So Gaudiya acaryas have followed Sridhara Swami. Logically, there was no good reason to consider them interpolations. Including them would bring the count to 18000 verses.

Comment: @RaRa *Including them would bring the count to 18000 verses.* -- You mean it would have 18000 verses according to what is discussed at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29674/2790 and also at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19689/2790 -- did you mean that?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa yes I meant that. Excluding them would make many verses missing so count of 18000 may not be reached. I have not counted personally. But since 5th Canto verses are extremely long. Some are twice or Thrice the normal length, verse count is not straight forward in bhagavatam.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I meant counting as in 2nd url, rather than first url.

Comment: @RaRa Yes, I know you meant 2nd link. The verses in the 5th canto are mostly written in prose.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa even in other cantos long verses can be seen here and there though not as much as 5th canto