# How many Puranas have critical editions?

Tags: puranas, resource, critical-edition

I have heard of a critical edition of Harivamsa prepared by BORI.  Are there any others and are they available on the net?

Comment: Related: [Is there a critical edition of Bhāgavata Purāṇa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29874)